# Is there a way to get the IE object when working with VDI & Citrix?

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, citrix, vdi

Is it possible to get the IE object using VBScript inside Citrix(VDI) ?

I already know I can run VBScripts and work with IE objects (If I create them first).

I have tried using the `GetObject` method as well as `WScript.Shell.Windows` method.

Answer (score 0):

can you try below script to check whether it is working or not.

```html
Dim IE
Dim MyDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 0
IE.navigate "https://google.com"
```

Let us know about your testing results.

Comment: I have tried this and it works. As stated in the question, it works when creating it first. The problem is when I try to get it when it is already opened.

Comment: @OvidiuPtr, You said when you try to fetch already opened IE object you faced some problem. Did you got any error? If yes, Then try to post your error message may help to find the issue. Also try to provide your sample code. We are not available with Citrix , but we can try to check whether code has some issue or not.